# VB6 + classic asp: developing activeX component

Tags: dll, vb6, asp-classic, activex

i've created a little activeX dll under vb6 which i'm running under classic asp.

my question:
once the dll is compiled it has write-protection caused by the IIS (access denied).
i have to completely stop the webserver, then recompile + restart the server again.

is there a more convenient way to do this? maybe even without having to compile?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't more convenient way. Once the DLL is loaded into memory by IIS it is locked and cannot be modified. You could write a simple VB script client in order to test the ActiveX without passing by IIS.